# Is it possible to save to NSUserDefault before first run?

Tags: nsuserdefaults, nsdata

I want to save a custom object array as NSData to NSUserDefaults that will be available at first run, is it possible? if so, how?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question? what do you mean "first run"?

Comment: have you tried anything? seems the logical place is to determine if it's first launch and if so do some logic in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: Let me refries my question.
Is it possible to launch app to appstore that already have my object inside the NSUserDefault?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the -registerDefaults: method to set any default values that you would like to have available before the user has set anything.